# Combinatorics/probability ballot problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose that there’s an election! Two candidates, Sherlock
and Moriarty, are running for office. Suppose that Sherlock receives
8 votes and Moriarty receives 7 votes, and that these votes are
being counted up one-by-one to create a running total.
What is the probability that Sherlock is never behind in this running total? In general, if Sherlock got s votes and Moriarty got m
votes, what is this probability?
Can anyone help me explain this problem? There seems to be a bunch of different cases here for which I have not figured out what the best approach is.

Comment: Reflection principle for random walks...

Comment: http://www.math.caltech.edu/~2016-17/2term/ma003/Notes/Lecture16.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I give the answer for the special case of $s=m=n$. Considering an opening bracket a vote for Sherlock and a closing bracket a vote for Moriarty, you're actually looking for the number of valid strings with $n$ pairs of brackets, which equals the $n^{th}$ [Catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Applications_in_combinatorics), i.e., $C_n$. Thus, the probability you're looking after in this special case equals:
$$\frac{C_n \times n! \times n!}{(2n)!}.$$